# Observable implementation in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been struggling understanding the Angular Observables but I can get it working.I am trying to get data to my dynamic navigation bar and I succeeded in verifying if user is logged in or not and so showing the Login or Logout button but I can't get user data.Below is my implementation

This is **user interface**:

```
 interface User{
 status:boolean,
 username:string,
 email:string
 }
```

**User service**:

```
export class UserService {

private Userr :BehaviorSubject<User>

 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
this.Userr = new BehaviorSubject<User>({
  status:false,
  username:"",
  email:""  
});
}
setUser(user:User){
this.Userr.next(user);
 }
 get getUserData(){
  return this.Userr.asObservable();
}
 get retrieveData(){
return this.http.get<User>('/api/userdata')
}
}
```

Below is my **navbar ts component** implementation:

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;        
 User$ : Observable<User>;
 constructor(private authService: AuthService,private router:Router,private 
 user:UserService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.getLoggedIn; 
 this.User$ = this.user.getUserData;
 }
 }
```

I didn't post the logout function to only focus about geting data.
And in **navbar html componenet** I have to following:

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="logout()" routerLink='/welcome'>Welcome 
{{User$.username}}!,Log Out!</a>
```

**And the error is that User$.username is undefined**.Thanks

**Edit**
   For anyone who face this problem the solution is to get the username as follows:

```
{{(User$ | async).username}}!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, because the User$ is an observable. So it hasn't returned yet. There are two choices:

1) `{{ (User$ | async).username }}` which is an Angular syntax to wait for the observable

2)

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;        
 User$ : Observable<User>;
 user: User = {};
 constructor(private authService: AuthService,private router:Router,private 
 user:UserService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.getLoggedIn; 
 this.User$ = this.user.getUserData.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
 }
 }

{{user.username}}
```

You can wait for the observable in a subscribe method and assign it to a user variable. When it returns, Angular will update the dom with the value of the username.

Comment: Ok you mean this.user.getUserData().subscribe(user => this.user = user);? as like you said returns an error, but now somehow I got an error while trying to log in core.js:1671 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: woops. Maybe I botched the syntax a little. you have a get on the getUserData, so you can scrap the parenthesis. Try this.user.getUserData.subscribe(user => this.user = user); Otherwise maybe just remove the get keyword to make it a function

Comment: Yea sorry I wrote it without parenthesis but I don't know why I am getting the error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded while I am trying to log in since it worked before

Comment: Ok I found the problem on the method ngonInit of navbar I also added after this.user=user the followin syntax this.User.setUser(user) // User in second case is service

Comment: could you take a look into my edited post please? I added something there

Comment: Taking a look now, sorry approved too fast

Comment: ok now please cause somehow I edited your com instead of my post

Comment: can you post cost for Auth? Im not positive what that is doing?

Comment: Ok I found that flatMap would work but I don't really understand how to implement it, do  you got any ideea?

Comment: Do get the stackoverflow, I guess in one on the subscriptions you are calling a .emit() which eventually triggers the subscription again. However, I can't see where that is happening. Can we take a step back. Whats the end goal? When a user logs in their name is shown in the navbar?

Comment: I got it working somehow by subscribing again then again (first to set the isloggedin observable to true then to set the user observable to user data) and yes the goal is to show in navbar like this:Welcome {{username}},log out

Comment: I got it working somehow by subscribing again then again (first to set the isloggedin observable to true then to set the user observable to user data) and yes when a user logs in the goal is to show in navbar like this:Welcome {{username}} and to redirect to dashboard where more info about user is required but now is working but not like I want, means that I have to hit 2 times  the log in button to actually beign redirect to dashboard and also when I am logged out from dashboard in navbar still have the message welcome!,log out, if you can help I can edit whole post

Comment: somehow I managed to subscribe to 2 observables by calling method Observable.combineLatest() and now everything is working but your post helped me as {{(User$ | async).username}} helps me to get the username of the user so I marked your post as correct answer